# What cause "java.io.IOException: BufferedReader is closed" on android?

Tags: java, android, io, bufferedreader

I got ANR in my application. Base on logs I found that my application was killed with signal 3. In stack trace I get info that code:

```
 if (mReceiver != null && mReceiver.isAlive()){
       mReceiver.interrupt();
       mReceiver = null;                
 }
 if (mReader != null) {
      mReader.close();// this line throws exception
      mReader = null;
 }
```

takes to long time.
In logs I got also info about exception thrown by above marked line.

```
05-17 14:04:48.343  3327  6535 W System.err: java.io.IOException: BufferedReader is closed 
05-17 14:04:48.343  3327  6535 W System.err: at java.io.BufferedReader.checkNotClosed(BufferedReader.java:204)
05-17 14:04:48.343  3327  6535 W System.err: at com.sec.android.app.radio.Receiver.run(Receiver.java:40)
```

but in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close%28%29
is:

> Nothing is done if this reader has already been closed.

so why this exception was thrown?

very similar logs I found only on http://yatse.leetzone.org/redmine/attachments/258/alogcat.2013-04-05-13-15-17+0100.txt#.UZ3YfNmwf5A

Respondign to below questions: I share the mReader to the one thread: mReceiver but I interrupt this thread before the colse the mReader.

Comment: Do you share the reader across threads? Is this the complete stacktrace?

Comment: are you using HTTPConnection Stream to read data?

Comment: post the code that you are using to read using BufferedReader.

Comment: Bug in android 2.3 and higher versions **http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562**

Comment: Some methods receive a Reader parameter, and close the stream themselves on end-of-file. The official Java can have an extra close, and even says so in the javadoc. So Android specific.

Comment: @Fildor after you suggestion I try to find a thread I more stack trace. And I found it. In my log is so many entries so this stack trace is very cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What cause “java.io.IOException: BufferedReader is closed” on android?

What causes it, on any platform, is that *you* closed the `BufferedReader`, or its underlying resource, and then continued to use it.